# The program stops running with an error code of 255 (0xFF)

Tags: c++, arrays, file

Having this as my heading code, with of course some includes up here:

I found out that when running the program, it crashes and sends me an error saying "Process returned 255 (0xFF)". When debugging, I found out that my program crashes when it finds a not corresponding code in the array, but that's what it's supposed to do the `cercaCens`. What it does is search in the array if the code exists, and if it does, return the position of where it is. If it's not in the array, return me false and the position = -3.

I'm not sure, but I think it crashes when the program interprets that the given code should be stored into an array when it shouldn't.
This is what I have stored into an array before I want to save other information when reading from the other file:

Comment: I did not check whole code (hence comment and not answer), but `esq <= dret` is suspicious. It can lead to attempt to access `taulaEstats[US_STATES]` which is out of array bounds.

Comment: Have you tried running the program with a memory tool, such as Valgrind or Dr. Memory (on Windows)?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Well doing that would consider much more errors, but it doesn't crash. Even though the program won't be running as I want it to run, I want it to consider as dret as a posible value, or it wouldn't just work as I wanted to.

Comment: @maga , set the initial value of dret to US_STATES - 1 then. Actually, most of the common implementation of binary serach threats `low/high` pair as open interval, so you might consider this.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Oh crap, forgot it, now worked! Thank you so much bro, I'm very new at the coding world! <3